# SQL server Currency Code if Invoice has one more than one currency

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is my requirement

```
Table1 - QuotationMaster - QuoteID,CustomerID,Date,InvoiceNo
Table2 - QuoteItems - QuoteID,ItemID,CurrencyID,Amount
Table3 - CurrencyMaster - CurrencyID,CurrencyCode
```

Example:

If I search for the invoice statement for a particular date, final result must be

**Date, CustomerName, CurrencyCode, Amount**

For a particular invoice if it has 2 items which has same CurrencyID
then result should be displayed as follow

Item1 - Amount (2.00)
Item2 - Amount (3.00)

```
Date   InvoiceNo  CustomerName    CurrencyCode   Amount
June    INV123     TESTING          INR           5.00
```

For a particular invoice if it has 2 items which has different CurrencyID's
then result should be displayed as follow

```
Date   InvoiceNo  CustomerName    CurrencyCode   Amount
June    INV123     TESTING          0          0.00
```

To make it simple if a invoice has two items with different currencies then the currency code and Amount must be 0.

I'm not able to get a clear picture how to solve this as I end up with groupby currencyid and get the same result printed twice

```
Date   InvoiceNo  CustomerName    CurrencyCode   Amount
June    INV123     TESTING          INR          2.00
June    INV123     TESTING          GBP          3.00
```

Can you please help me with the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I understand this right, you basically want to group the items by `quoteid` and filter for those where the maximum `currencyid` is no equal to the minimum `currencyid` in the `HAVING` clause. (If all currency IDs are equal the minimum is equal to the maximum.)

Then left join this to your quotes table and left join the currency table to get the code.

Check in a case if the currency ID `IS NULL`. If it is, the items of the quote had different currency ids (or all were `NULL` which means they were different, by the tri state logic).

As you didn't describe you customer table the customer name isn't selected. You'll have to add that yourself.

```
SELECT qm1.date,
       qm1.invoiceno,
       CASE
         WHEN qi2.quoteid IS NULL
           THEN cm1.currencycode
         ELSE
           '0'
       END currencycode,
       CASE
         WHEN qi2.quoteid IS NULL
           THEN qi2.amount
         ELSE
           0
       END amount
       FROM quotationmaster qm1
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT qi1.quoteid,
                              sum(qi1.amount) amount,
                              max(qi1.currencyid) currencyid
                              FROM quoteitems qi1
                              GROUP BY qi1.quoteid
                              HAVING max(qi1.currencyid) = min(qi1.currencyid)) qi2
                      ON qi2.quoteid = qm1.quoteid
            LEFT JOIN currencymaster cm1
                      ON cm1.currencyid = cm1.qurrencyid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT sub.QuoteID,
    sub.CustomerID,
    sub.Date,
    sub.InvoiceNo,
    sub.ItemID,
    IIF(sub.ItemCount = sub.CurrencyCount, sub.CurrencyID, 0) AS CurrencyID
    sub.Amount,
FROM (
    SELECT qm.QuoteID,
        qm.CustomerID,
        qm.Date,
        qm.InvoiceNo,
        qi.ItemID,
        qi.CurrencyID,
        qi.Amount,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY qi.QuoteID) AS ItemCount,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY qi.QuoteID, qi.CurrencyID) AS CurrencyCount
    FROM QuotationMaster AS qm
        INNER JOIN QuoteItems AS qi
            ON qi.QuoteID = qm.QuoteID
) AS sub
-- You can use it also for a join (a 'n/a'-Currency in CurrencyMaster with ID=0 is required)
-- INNER JOIN CurrencyMaster AS cm
--  ON cm.CurrencyID = IIF(sub.ItemCount = sub.CurrencyCount, sub.CurrencyID, 0)
-- OR Use LEFT OUTER JOIN if you dont have a Fallback-Value in CurrencyMaster.
```